# How to read a string file and convert to int

Tags: c#, list

I'm new to C# and I have been searching around for a while for a solution to this, although nothing I try seems to work :(

```
public Form1()         
{ 
    InitializeComponent();        
    File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Simon\test.txt");
    ???
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    List<string> newlist = highscores.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.ToString());
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Simon\test.txt", newlist);
}
```

This is my code right now, and as you can see I successfully managed to write the highscores (list) to a file by converting the ints to string and writing them. Now I have to read them and convert them back to ints (later on in my code, the player adds ints by creating new high scores). I tried using the convert method but nothing I do seems to work, I'm not sure if I should be using an array here but it would surprise me considering I've only used lists. As I said, I'm new to programming so I could use a little help on this one :p

EDIT WITH MORE INFO: Sorry for the lack of info, but highscores is a list. Everytime the player gets a new highscore a new entry is created, and kept at a max of 5. This is what I'm trying to get on to a text file so the high scores can "be saved" and retrieved when the program is started again. I'm having problems getting the highscores back into the list when the program is launched.

SOME MORE CODE:
global variables

```
List<int> highscores = new List<int>(); 
int totaltime = 0;
int timeleft = 3;
```

how the list works and what comes into it. the aim of the game is to dodge as many sqaures as possible, if it intersects the following happens.

```
if (picturebox.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox1.Bounds))
                {
                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(668, 580);
                    pictureBox2.Location = new Point(622, 30);
                    timer4.Stop();
                    timer3.Stop();
                    timer2.Stop();
                    timer1.Stop();
                    timer4.Interval = 1000;
                    label2.Hide();
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("You died! You lasted " + totaltime + " seconds.");

                    if (highscores.Count < 5)
                    {
                        highscores.Add(totaltime);
                        highscores.Sort();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int newscore = totaltime;
                        int lowestscore = int.MaxValue;
                        foreach (int score in highscores)
                        {
                            if (score < lowestscore)
                                lowestscore = score;
                        }
                        if (newscore > lowestscore)
                        {
                            highscores.Remove(lowestscore);
                            highscores.Add(newscore);
                            highscores.Sort();
                        }
                    }
                    textBox1.Clear();
                    for (int n = highscores.Count - 1; n >= 0; n--)
                        textBox1.AppendText(highscores[n].ToString() + "\n");

                    totaltime = 0;
                    timeleft = 3;
                    label5.Text = "0";

                    foreach (PictureBox pic in pbspawn)
                    {
                        if (pic != pictureBox2)
                            this.Controls.Remove(pic);
                    }
                    pbspawn = new List<PictureBox>();

                }
```

If there is anything else I can add to clarify please say so.

Comment: Look into serializers.  `NewtonSoft.Json`, or `Xml.XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: Please learn to include all of the information necessary to reproduce a problem. You haven't even told us the data type of `highscores`, much less have you shown us how it is defined or how it is populated.

Answer (score 0):

try using linq

make sure to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your scripts

The [`.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) [clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) takes a [predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) for a [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) which [returns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) you an [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), and by using a [lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx) [operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx), assign a [variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691160%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for each [iterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby.aspx) in your starting [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which in this case is the `intList`, and each [iterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby.aspx) i assign as `item`. after the [lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx) [operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) you pretty much do with it whatever you want, and the [`.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) [clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) will custom make an [`IEnumarable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for you as you so wish.

```
IEnumerable<int> intList = newlist.Select(item => Int.Parse(item));
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem, this is the reverse action

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Simon\test.txt");
var highscores = lines.Select(x => int.Parse(x));
```